# Need to prove that convex property is the intersection of an increasing and decreasing property for graph

Tags: logic, graph-theory, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I need to prove that any convex property for graphs can always be expressed as the intersection of an increasing property and decreasing property for graph, specifically that:

$\forall A\subset B\subset C ~~$ and a property $~~Q~~$ if $~~Q\in A \land Q\in C \implies Q\in B $.

I did the following using logic: $\forall A\subset B\subset C$
$$Q\in A \land Q\in C \iff Q\in A$$ so $$Q\in A \implies Q\in B $$
by the same argument:
$$Q \in A \land Q\in C \iff Q\in C$$ therefore
$$Q\in C \implies Q \in B$$

That is for all $A, B, C$ such that $A\subset B \subset C$. My question arises in how can i combine the two previous results to get the the desired intersection or something like $\forall A\subset B \subset C$ $(Q\in A \implies Q\in B) \land (Q\in C \implies Q \in B)$ which will result in the intersection of an increasing property and decreasing prrperty by definition.

Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be confusing certain things in your question, in particular the subgraph relation and logical implication. You should first try solving this problem without the language of logic that seems to harm rather than help, you can always make the proof formal afterwards. You should probably talk to a prof, it would be hard to help you on this QA site, given the present state of your question (which explains the lack of interest this question got).